# custom error message for required field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to add custom message for the project field which is required is account field value is not 0.

> Error message displaying now :The project name field is required
>   unless account name is in 0.

I want to display as

> The Project Name is Required

```
     $messages=[
            'project_name.required'=>'The Project Name is Required',
          ]; 
     $this->validate($request,[
     'account_name'=>'required',
     'project_name'=>'required_unless:account_name,0',
      ],$messages);
```

What I have to change in my code

Comment: For validation nitifications at admin side better use html requiered  + parsley.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should replace `require` with `required_unless`

```
$messages=[
        'project_name.required_unless'=>'The Project Name is Required',
      ];
```

laravel document:

> Sometimes you may wish to specify a custom error messages only for a
>   specific field. You may do so using "dot" notation. Specify the
>   attribute's name first, followed by the rule

Answer (score 0):

There is the best way:

```
$rules = [
    'account_name' => 'required',
    'project_name' => 'required_unless:account_name,0',
];
$messages=[
    'project_name.required_unless' => 'The :attribute is required if the value of :other is different from the following values: :values.',
];
$attributes = [
    'project_name' => 'Project Name',
    'account_name' => 'Account Name',
];

$this->validate($request, $rules, $messages, $attributes);
```

The error message will be: `The Project Name is required if the value of Account Name is different from the following values: 0.`

**The way is also compatible with required_if, required_with, same, and other rules with two attributes.**